# Existence of one series to use for comparison test.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, divergent-series

Does there exist $f(n)>n\ln n$ such that
$$\sum_{n=k}^\infty\frac{1}{f(n)}$$
**diverges**?

If so, is there a maximum such $f(n)$?

Of course the answer to the last question I suppose would eliminate the need for all convergence tests (given that the series is not alternating)!

Comment: You may be interested in [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/82998/prove-divergence-and-conclude-that-there-is-no-universal-smallest-comparison-s).

Comment: Liad, no.  Series will converge in that case.

Comment: More simply: suppose $\sum a_n$ is infinite with $a_n>0$.  Choose $n_1$ so that $a_1+\cdots+a_{n_1}>1$. Replace each of these $a_i$ with $a_i/2$. Now choose $n_2$ so that $a_{n_1+1}+\cdots+a_{n_2}>1$. replace each of these $a_i$ with $a_i/3$. Continue... You'll wind up with a "smaller" divergent series.

Comment: But the infinite sum of $\frac {1}{n\ln n}$ converges so as it's tail. If there exsist such $f$ then by comparison test $\frac {1}{n\ln n}$ must diverge. Am I wrong?

Comment: Snufsan, that sum does not converge.  Use the integral test.

Comment: David Mitra, there is no $sup$ of this set?  I get the math, but this seems like a paradox.  BTW I would still like to have a few examples.  Perhaps with $ln(n)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By [Cauchy's condensation test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test), all the following series are divergent:
$$ \sum_{n\geq n_0}\frac{1}{n\log(n)},\qquad \sum_{n\geq n_0}\frac{1}{n\log(n)\log\log(n)},\qquad \sum_{n\geq n_0}\frac{1}{n\log(n)\log\log(n)\log\log\log(n)} $$
and all the following series are convergent:
$$ \sum_{n\geq n_0}\frac{1}{n\log(n)^2},\qquad\! \sum_{n\geq n_0}\frac{1}{n\log(n)\log\log(n)^2},\qquad \!\sum_{n\geq n_0}\frac{1}{n\log(n)\log\log(n)\log\log\log(n)^2} $$
so there is clearly no maximum.
 In each case, $n_0$ is chosen in such a way that every term of the corresponding sum makes sense.

Comment: Sorry, the "clearly" part eludes me.  Continue your progression of divergent series ad infinitum.  There is no $sup$ of the denominator?  it is easy to get a convergent series from any of the series in this set by repeating any factor, i.e. multiplicity 2 or more.  But if we don't do that, then....?

Comment: NVM.  I see it.  Any product of divergent expressions will also diverge - so clearly so $sup$.  Thanks.

Comment: I was going to say that you may simply add extra $\log\log\log\ldots$ factors in the denominators of a series in the first line, preserving divergence.